# Parsing json from url in android :

Tags: android, json

I tried to request the URI bellow and parse it response a lot of ways. But I don't know what is the problem with my code below.

```
    String url = "http://10.0.2.2/ipf/conx.php";

    // Get HttpResponse Object from url.
    // Get HttpEntity from Http Response Object
    Log.v("Log1", "msg1");
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost method = new HttpPost(url);
    Log.v("Log1", "msg2");
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(method);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        Log.v("Log2", "msg1");
    } else {
        Log.v("log2", "msg2");
    }
```

When I follow my logcat print, I can see only:
log1( msg1 and 2 )

Please take some help 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes sometime(depends upon your internet speed) to get the response from the server....!
Or you can use below class to check when the response come,

```
private class xyz extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog ;
    private Activity mActivity;
    public xyz(Activity activity)
    {
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog = new ProgressDialog(mActivity);
        this.dialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        this.dialog.show();
        //code which load at prefix time

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            // make code which you want in background
String url = "http://10.0.2.2/ipf/conx.php";

    // Get HttpResponse Object from url.
    // Get HttpEntity from Http Response Object
    Log.v("Log1", "msg1");
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost method = new HttpPost(url);
    Log.v("Log1", "msg2");
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(method);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        Log.v("Log2", "msg1");
    } else {
        Log.v("log2", "msg2");
    }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();

        }

    }
}
```

Use this this in your activity class like this,

```
new xyz(ActivityClassName.this).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility of 2 issues here.

1- check if you have added proper network permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml file.

2- your code is executing a network request directly on main thread which Android does not allow. You have to execute this in worker thread e.g. use AsyncTask

It will be much better if you also put the log in your question.